# How to scrape last string of <p> tag element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

To start, python is my first language I am learning.
I am scraping a website for rent prices across my city and I am using `BeautifulSoup` to get the price data, but I am unable to get the value of this

tag.

Here is the tag:

```
<p><strong class="hidden show-mobile-inline">Monthly Rent: </strong>2,450 +</p>
```

Here is my code:

```
text = soup.find_all("div", {"class", "plan-group rent"})
for item in text:
    rent = item.find_all("p")
    for price in rent:
        print(price.string)
```

I also tried:

```
text = soup.find_all("div", {"class", "plan-group rent"})
for item in text:
    rent = item.find_all("p")
    for price in rent:
        items = price.find_all("strong")
        for item in items:
            print('item.string')
```

and that works to print out "Monthly Rent:" but I don't understand why I can't get the actual price. The above code shows me that the monthly rent is in the strong tag, which means that the p tag only contains the price which is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @kyrony there are two children in your `<p>` - Cause you select the `<strong>` you will only get one of the texts.

You could use different approaches [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
list(soup.p.stripped_strings)[-1]
```

or [`contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

```
soup.p.contents[-1]
```

or with [`recursive` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument)

```
soup.p.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<p><strong class="hidden show-mobile-inline">Monthly Rent: </strong>2,450 +</p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.p.contents[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically your content has two children

```
<p><strong class="hidden show-mobile-inline">Monthly Rent: </strong>2,450 +</p>
```

A strong tag

```
<strong class="hidden show-mobile-inline">Monthly Rent: </strong>
```

and a string

```
2,450 +
```

The string method in beautiful soup only takes one argument so its going to return None. In order to get the second string you need to use the [stripped_strings](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=stripped_strings#strings-and-stripped-strings) generator.