# Extracting text from a nested tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following is the nested tag I would like to proceed with

```
<h5><span class="price">31.8 萬</span>2014 NISSAN MARCH</h5>
```

And here is my successful attempt to extract price unit.

```
price = i.find("span", attrs = {"class" : "price"})
```

However, when i tried

```
name = i.find("h5").span.find_next_sibling(text=True)
```

it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'. I hope there is a solution that is similar to my successful attempt. Thank you. ; )

Edit: The following is my complete code.

```
def get_basic_info(content_list):
    basic_info = []
    for item in content_list:
        basic_info.append(item.find_all('h5'))
    return basic_info

names = []
def get_names(basic_info):
    for item in basic_info:
        for i in item:
            name = i.find("span", attrs = {"class" : "price"}).find_next_sibling()
        if name:
            names.append(name.text)
          
    return(names)

for page in range(1,18):
    base_url = "https://www.easycar.tw/carList.php?Action=search&show=col&lifting=desc&year=&year1=&page="+ str(page)
    response = get(base_url, headers=headers)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    content_list = html_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'caption'})
    basic_info = get_basic_info(content_list)
    names = get_names(basic_info)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape last string of <p> tag element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101134/how-to-scrape-last-string-of-p-tag-element)

Comment: I will try understanding it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to get your goal - Selecting the correct `<h5>` you could dive a bit deeper with this answer: [How to scrape last string of <p> tag element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101134/how-to-scrape-last-string-of-p-tag-element)

Following your example iterate all `<span>` of your selection - Used [`css selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) here to be more specific:

```
for e in soup.select('h5 span.price'):
    print(e.next_sibling.strip())
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.easycar.tw/carList.php?Action=search&show=col&lifting=desc&year=&year1=&page=1'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).text)

for e in soup.select('h5 span.price'):
    print(e.next_sibling.strip())
    ### or getting only car names
    print(e.next_sibling.strip().split(' ', 1)[-1])
```

##### Output

```
2020 TOYOTA ALTIS
2019 NISSAN LIVINA
2019 TOYOTA VIOS
2016 HONDA CITY
2017 HONDA HR-V
2018 TOYOTA YARIS
...
```

or

```
TOYOTA ALTIS
NISSAN LIVINA
TOYOTA VIOS
HONDA CITY
HONDA HR-V
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`i.find("h5").span.find_next_sibling(text=True)` should give you '2014 NISSAN MARCH' but you are not getting the correct `h5` I am sure. You should try printing out `i.find("h5")` to see if its the correct heading you want. Alternatively, you can get the answer you want by

`soup.find("span", attrs = {"class" : "price"}).find_next_sibling(text=True)`

---

Edit after question was updated:

Since the `i` in loop is already a `h5` `Tag` object,
we don't have to find it. Here is the updated code that works

`i.span.find_next_sibling(text=True)`

Comment: I did successfully extract h5, but I just couldn't get the car names no matter what Ive tried.

Comment: Yes, I have refactored the answer with the updated code. The problem was that the `i` in loop was already `bs4.element.Tag` object of the `h5` element. So when we tried to find `h5` on that, we didn't receive anything. And when we tried to find the `span` then we lost context of the tags around it, so we couldn't get the next sibling. I hope this helps.

Comment: It gives me 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'. Is this the problem of my code or the problem of google collab.... I feel like I am close to the answer, thanks for helping

Comment: I understand. You will want to use `names.append(name.strip())` to just get the text without the spaces and newlines. `.text` didn't give me such error, so might be a version difference.