# How to remove a tag when scraping

Tags: python, django, screen-scraping

```
<p class="hidden-xs text-muted">
<b>GMC:</b>
123456
</p>
```

I simply need the GMC number from here which will appear as GMC : 123456 when I scrape it.
How to remove the `"b"` tag from there?
I am using python 3.10.5 and BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def proxy_request(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


url = "www.domain.com" # not mentioning the domain here

soup = proxy_request(url)

media_body = soup.find("div", {"class":"media-body"}) 
 
gmc_number = media_body.p.text.strip()
```

output is like this,
GMC:
123456
expected output,
123456

Comment: You can filter using regex `import re re.findall(r"\d+",media_body.p.text.strip())[0]`

Comment: Your code searches for a `div`, but this is a `p`?

Comment: @simpleApp: please *don't* use regexes in context free languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape last string of <p> tag element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101134/how-to-scrape-last-string-of-p-tag-element)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem suggested operation is on string, am I missing something here?  objective was not to abuse regex.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it is easier to just return the result next to the `b` tag:

```
media_body = soup.find('div', {'class':'media-body'})
gmc_number = media_body.p.b.next_sibling.text.strip()
```

This will work with the node immediately following the `</b>`. If this is thus a text node (`NavigableString`) with the GMC number, we retrieve that one.

Answer (score 0):

Split the text at the colon character `:` and takes the last element, which is the GMC number and removes any white space using the `strip` method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def proxy_request(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


url = "www.domain.com" # not mentioning the domain here

soup = proxy_request(url)

media_body = soup.find("div", {"class":"media-body"}) 
gmc_number = media_body.p.text.split(':')[-1].strip()
```